# How can we create slider menu with submenu in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, slider

I am working on swift and trying to create slider menu, in advance want to show submenu for some menus, I am trying to keep things simple, right now I am done with slider menu using tablview to show menus but facing difficulty to create submenu, is there any more clean way to solve my problem?

[image]

Comment: What is a slider menu? Maybe post a screenshot what you would like to have?

Comment: @NilsZiehn I think Sandesh mean like a js-slider you find on a lot of different websites? Except written in Sift native to iOS instead of the web version. Maybe something along the lines of a scroll view and a UIPageControl would work for him.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a Multilevel TableView. A simple solution to this will be to dynamically update the number of rows when a cell is tapped.

You need to create an array of n+1 rows for each section:
- (Section 1), Row 1
-- (Section 1), Row 2
--  (Section 1), Row 3
- (Section 2), Row 1
--  (Section 2), Row 2
--  (Section 2), Row 3

First row of each section represents you top level rows (Send Money, Status Checker, etc) and the others represent the sub-section (Personal Information, etc).
You need to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` methods to only display the first row of each section. Create a property the will contain an optional `NSIndexPath` that represents the selected `section`. In the `dataSource` methods check if there's a value in this property and return all the rows that correspond to the appropriate section.

Comment: thanks, can u know replacement for "isShowingList" in objective to swift